# SpreadsheetGear.shapes.IPictureFormat's getImage method is not available for Version7.4.1.104

Tags: spreadsheetgear

I am migrating Spreadsheet Gear 6.0.3.190 to 7.4.1.104. I am getting "IPictureFormat doesnot contain the definition for GetImage" Can any one help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

This IPictureFormat.GetImage is removed  from the core API and replaced with SpreadsheetGear.Drawing.Image.GetImage in SpreadsheetGear2012.Drawing.dll.

Comment: For this and other breaking changes between SpreadsheetGear 2010 and 2012, see http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012_Breaking_Changes.html

Comment: Thank you.I didnt check this while i am posting that question after that I have verified this URL which u provided in my previous question.It worked and saved my time too.Thank you so much.!!